# Why is type parameter treated as object in expression?

Tags: c#, linq, generics, expression

Learning LINQ expressions I found out a strange behaviour. Please have a look at the following class. It may seem to be not very handy, but it's only an example.

```
class IntTestClass
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    Func<IntTestClass, bool> check;

    public IntTestClass(int _id)
    {
        Id = _id;

        Expression<Func<IntTestClass, int>> GetId = tc => tc.Id;

        Expression<Func<int, bool>> e1 = i => i.Equals(Id);
        var equals1 = (e1.Body as MethodCallExpression).Method;
        string s1 = equals1.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(s1);

        var x1 = Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(Id), equals1, GetId.Body);
        var exp1 = (Expression<Func<IntTestClass, bool>>)
                             Expression.Lambda(x1, GetId.Parameters.ToArray());
        check = exp1.Compile();
    }

    public bool Check(IntTestClass t)
    {
        var result =  check(t);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Just to run a test one may use:

```
var intTestClass= new IntTestClass(0);
intTestClass.Check(new IntTestClass(0)); //true
intTestClass.Check(new IntTestClass(1)); //false
```

Then I tried to make this class generic:

```
class TestClass<T>
{
    public T Id { get; private set; }

    public TestClass(T _Id)
    {
        Id = _Id;

        Expression<Func<TestClass<T>, T>> GetId = tc => tc.Id;

        Expression<Func<T, bool>> e1 = i => i.Equals(Id);
        var equals1 = (e1.Body as MethodCallExpression).Method;
        string s1 = equals1.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(s1);

        var x1 = Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(Id), equals1, GetId.Body);
        ....
    }
    ....
}
```

So when I try to run similar code:

```
 var testClass = new TestClass<int>(0);
```

it throws an exception on line initializing `x1` variable in constructor, saying

> Expression of type 'System.Int32' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Object' of method 'Boolean Equals(System.Object)'

So it appears that `equals1` (containing `MethodInfo` of the `Equals` method) in the `TestClass<T>` constructor is `Boolean Equals(System.Object)`

But in `IntTestClass` constructor `equals1` is `Boolean Equals(Int32)`.

Why is that so? In the generic class in runtime `T` is of type `System.Int32`. Why does the expression in `e1` variable use `Equals` from the `System.Object` class, but not from `System.Int32`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is because manual building of expression trees needs a knowledge of tricks, that compiler does for you when you write regular code.

You can solve this particular problem in two ways:

1) Convert the `int`-expression into `object`-expression:

```
var x1 = Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(Id), equals1, Expression.Convert(GetId.Body, typeof(object)));
```

This will add conversion code for `Object.Equals` method argument, which, in turn, will provide boxing, when you'll call compiled lambda.

2) Put a constraint to your generic:

```
class TestClass<T>
    where T : IEquatable<T>
{
}
```

and leave this line:

```
var x1 = Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(Id), equals1, GetId.Body);
```

unchanged.

The constraint here helps to tell, that you're going to use `IEquatable<T>.Equals(T)` instead of `Object.Equals`. `IEquatable<T>.Equals(T)` doesn't need any argument conversions, because it is generic itself.

Comment: I used the second approach...It does the job...Could you, please, give me some link for reading on the topic?...as this behaviour remains rather vague.

Comment: @horgh: unfortunately, I can't give you any link... just don't know where this particular aspect can be examined. But there is no any vagueness: consider expression trees as a raw code, without any compiler tricks and syntax sugar. The things you just don't observe, when writing code (data conversions, method group conversions to delegate instances) should be written in expression trees explicitly.

Comment: After your edit on `IEquatable` actually everything took its place...Thanks a lot